# App crash when I touch specific cell in UITableView

Tags: ios, tableview, favorite

I have `Maintableview`(a `UIViewController`) with contents and `detailview`(a `UIViewController`) that show detail for each of cells in Maintableview.
I have added a "favorite" button in "**detailview**" that user can add to `Favoritetableview`(a `UIViewController`) and every thing work fine.

Now I have added "add to favorite" in `Maintableview` with swipe to left.
It adds contents successfully to `Favoritetableview` but when I touch that cell in `Favoritetableview` the app crashes.

Below is the console logs for the crash:

```
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a871d85 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010a2e3deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a75a934 -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:] + 164
    3   iranbirds                           0x00000001075cf672 -[FavoriteTableViewController prepareForSegue:sender:] + 530
    4   UIKit                               0x00000001090c55d5 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _performWithDestinationViewController:sender:] + 369
    5   UIKit                               0x00000001090c5433 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 82
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000108b1b5f8 -[UIViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:] + 99
    7   iranbirds                           0x00000001075cf42d -[FavoriteTableViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] + 189
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000108ac51c6 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1887
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000108ac541b -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 388
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000108989f62 _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 317
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010899de4c _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 95
    12  UIKit                               0x00000001089aa147 _afterCACommitHandler + 90
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a796c37 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a796ba7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a78c7fb __CFRunLoopRun + 1147
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a78c0f8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    17  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010be6bad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    18  UIKit                               0x000000010897df09 UIApplicationMain + 171
    19  iranbirds                           0x00000001075d32ef main + 111
    20  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010ba6492d start + 1
    21  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

---

favorite table view:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = (NSIndexPath *)sender;
    Favorite *fav = (Favorite *)[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *combinedName = fav.name;

    if  ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"FavoriteBirdDetail"])
    {
        GeneralViewController *detailViewController = (GeneralViewController*)[segue destinationViewController];

        detailViewController.birdName = [combinedName componentsSeparatedByString:@"^"][0];;
        detailViewController.sciName = [combinedName componentsSeparatedByString:@"^"][1];;
        detailViewController.managedOjbectContext = self.managedOjbectContext;
    }

}
```

This line cause error:
`detailViewController.sciName = [combinedName componentsSeparatedByString:@"^"][1];`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which line does it crash on?  You have tried to access the second element of an array with one element

Comment: Please update with crashlog!!

Comment: i found crash line.but when comment that line cause user can add same cell twice to favoritetaableview.(one time from detail and another time from swipe to left from main table view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
detailViewController.sciName = [combinedName componentsSeparatedByString:@"^"][1];
```

Well, look at this code - you are getting second object from an array by subscript syntax. And the code would work if an array contains at least 2 items.

It looks like your array contains zero or one element, that is why app crashes when you try to get an element by 1 index - `[1]`, which means the second element.

To prevent crash you should check an array `count` property before:

```
NSArray *anArray = [combinedName componentsSeparatedByString:@"^"]; 

if anArray.count >= 2 {
    detailViewController.sciName = anArray[1];
}
```

Comment: thanks.its fixed .but i still have problem with duplicate cell thats added to favoritetaableview.(one time from detail and another time from swipe to left from main table view)

Comment: Ok, if my answer helped you - please accept it, cell duplication is another question, and you should ask it separately.